# Where are the ChaCha20 test vectors/examples?

Tags: algorithm-design, salsa20, test-vectors, chacha

I see in the [Salsa20 specification](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf) there are test examples throughout the document to help an implementer make sure every function works as designed. Consequently the whole algorithm would work perfectly if all the tests pass. Without these test vectors it would be very difficult to know whether the code was working as designed or was giving incorrect outputs. [Test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) should be the gold standard for developing a cryptographic library.

So it came as a surprise to me when reading the *improved* [ChaCha20 specification](http://cr.yp.to/chacha/chacha-20080128.pdf) that there are no test examples to validate against. I have even had a look on the [ChaCha web page](http://cr.yp.to/chacha.html) but found nothing.

Even though ChaCha20 has better diffusion and is supposedly more secure, I would consider myself actually *safer* using the Salsa20 algorithm as I have reference test vectors for the code/library to validate against and I would *know* for sure that it was implemented correctly. Using ChaCha20 would be a risky move in comparison. How do all the other implementers of ChaCha20 e.g. OpenSSH know their implementation is correct? How are other people able to trust that their implementation is correct?

I would like to know where the ChaCha20 test examples are which show the correct outputs from the ChaCha quarter-round and ChaCha matrix? Why aren't they in the specification document?

Comment: You can generate your own test vectors with the reference implementation.

Comment: @orlp - except its missing some macro definitions, like `U32TO8_LITTLE` ad `U8TO32_LITTLE`. I have not been able to find it in the `ecrypt-sync.h` header file or the various `chacha.c` files.

Answer (score 12):

There are in the RFC : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-agl-tls-chacha20poly1305-04#section-7

> The following blocks contain test vectors for ChaCha20.  The first    line contains the 256-bit key, the second the 64-bit nonce and the
> last line contains a prefix of the resulting ChaCha20 key-stream.
>
> KEY:       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 00000000
> NONCE:     0000000000000000
> KEYSTREAM: 76b8e0ada0f13d90405d6ae55386bd28bdd219b8a08ded1aa836efcc
> 8b770dc7da41597c5157488d7724e03fb8d84a376a43b8f41518a11c
> c387b669b2ee6586
>
> KEY:       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 00000001
> NONCE:     0000000000000000
> KEYSTREAM: 4540f05a9f1fb296d7736e7b208e3c96eb4fe1834688d2604f450952
> ed432d41bbe2a0b6ea7566d2a5d1e7e20d42af2c53d792b1c43fea81
> 7e9ad275ae546963
>
> KEY:       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 00000000
> NONCE:     0000000000000001
> KEYSTREAM: de9cba7bf3d69ef5e786dc63973f653a0b49e015adbff7134fcb7df1
> 37821031e85a050278a7084527214f73efc7fa5b5277062eb7a0433e
> 445f41e3
>
> KEY:       00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 00000000
> NONCE:     0100000000000000
> KEYSTREAM: ef3fdfd6c61578fbf5cf35bd3dd33b8009631634d21e42ac33960bd1
> 38e50d32111e4caf237ee53ca8ad6426194a88545ddc497a0b466e7d
> 6bbdb0041b2f586b

Comment: Note that this is no RFC yet, it's only a draft.

Comment: The finalized RFC is here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7539/

Answer (score 5):

You'll find the test vector in a draft "Test Vectors for the Stream Cipher ChaCha draft-strombergson-chacha-test-vectors-00" available at the following link: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-strombergson-chacha-test-vectors-00
The document links a github repo where you can find all the vectors https://github.com/secworks/chacha_testvectors/

Another interesting reading: http://insanecoding.blogspot.fr/2014/06/avoid-incorrect-chacha20-implementations.html

You may also find others test vectors for ChaCha20 implementation in Draft "ChaCha20 and Poly1305 based Cipher Suites for TLS draft-agl-tls-chacha20poly1305-00" (Section 7) available at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-agl-tls-chacha20poly1305-00.