# How to implement HMAC SHA-256

Tags: algorithm-design, hmac, sha-256

I am trying to figure out how the HMAC SHA-256 hashing algorithm works. I know that we have to use the following:

```
H (K ^ opad)|| H ((K ^ ipad)|| text)).
```

The problem that I am facing is I think of basic understanding of the above. As far as I know, SHA-256 takes in *“character input”*. The key that I am using is of 256 bits in size and that leads (`K^ipad`) to be a 512 bit number. How do I use that to get the desired hash?

Comment: SHA-256, like almost every hash algorithm, is defined in terms of *bit* inputs.  Whether those bits happen to represent characters, images, packets, or something else doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Also note that `K^ipad` is an XOR, which will not change the length of `K`. That said, SHA-256 can input of arbitrary length (for practical intents and purposes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA-256 is defined for inputting and outputting binary data using bits. Most libraries only perform calculations based on byte input instead of bit input though. So in general, SHA-256 operates on bytes, not on characters.

You need to explicitly encode your characters to to bytes using *character encoding* such as UTF-8 to use SHA-256. Some platforms have an implicit conversion to bytes, or even equate characters with bytes (the `char` type in C/C++), but it is better to use explicit conversion none-the-less.

Never confuse characters and bytes, it's the source of about half of the problems with cryptography on stackoverflow (as well as countless bugs on system in the field, not just concerning cryptography).

---

When comparing the implementation of your library, don't test against random sites on the internet; they usually get encoding/decoding wrong as well. Instead compare with [test vectors](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4231#section-4.2) that do make clear which bytes are actually processed.

**After** you succeed with the official test vectors, you could perform string comparison with known good libraries (Java, OpenSSL etc.) using code for which the string encoding is explicitly specified.

Comment: I tried. I implemented SHA256 and it works like a charm. But when I try to implement this, the answer does not match the one that i get from an online calculator. The values I used for the key and message are: Key: `256'h603deb1015ca71be2b73aef0857d77811f352c073b6108d72d9810a30914dff4`; Message: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaabcdef`; The answer I get from hashing twice is: `256'hd48ea6df738d5791c9ca0d7ece4f0e76006bd01f3a2b917d7e1316515d1ac951`; The answer from online calculator is: `256'hc4da6a966d776db66de44e16904069c9feeca90d8f160d443b2fe0fea8dc7d2b`; I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Question: Do the initial hash values for the outer hashing remain the ones pre-defined or do we change those to the hash values we get after the inner-hashing?

Comment: What online calculator, could you point it out to me? What encoding does it use? PS don't prefix `256'h` to your code.

Comment: I used two of them and both give the same result.

[link](http://jetcityorange.com/hmac/)

Comment: OK, so they perform *character encoding for the key value* as well, while you are specifying hex characters. This may mean that you are using hex decoded bytes instead. And their sample key is in hex; brilliantly stupid - don't use code from random sites!

Comment: Well, thanks for all your help. Although I am still confused whether or not the result my code generates is correct or not.

PS I am using Verilog to implement these hashing algorithms.

Comment: The online encoder is correct if you interpret the key `256'h603deb1015ca71be2b73aef0857d77811f352c073b6108d72d9810a30914dff4` as ASCII. However, if I input your message without quotation marks I get `292ed0240964c62dc685ebf028801fdb4e5895a1f908c7c824dd53a993fc4e66` (and the same on Java).

Comment: I checked against the first given test vector and my code gives the correct result. I don't know whether to be happy that my code actually works or to feel incredibly stupid that I wasted the whole day trying to get the same answer as the online calculator.

I cannot thank you enough, good Sir. :)

Comment: Remember: for almost all crypto algorithms there are test vectors available online: see my question [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18393/1172) for possible locations (that was about block ciphers, but the same thing goes for HMAC's etc). One day does not sound too bad, actually, you can easily try forever if you don't know the exact binary input to a cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: I will remember that. And again, thank you. You just saved me 24 more hours of pulling my hair and questioning my sanity as well as coding ability. :)

Comment: @UtshashDas It would be nice if you could accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark on the left side of it) if the answer was what you were looking for. That way, the system (and we) know that your question has been answered to your satisfaction. Thank you in advance.