# Test vectors for PRESENT algorithm?

Tags: test-vectors, present

I'm looking for Test Vectors to test my implementation of PRESENT. I would like to test a different input from the usual where the key and the plaintext are either 000..000 or FFF...FFF.

Comment: Maybe read the [introduction paper (pp. 16 / Appendix I)](https://www.emsec.rub.de/media/crypto/attachments/files/2010/04/present_ches2007.pdf) to the end next time? Usually testvectors are appendices.

Answer (score 3):

There are many sources presenting the test vectors.

But you can also extract it from sourcecode implementations as [opencores.org](http://opencores.org/websvn,filedetails?repname=present&path=%2Fpresent%2Ftrunk%2FDecode%2Fbench%2Fvhdl%2FPresentFullDecoderTB.vhd) et al offer them…

> ```
>  Plaintext: 0000000000000000
>
>  Key: 00000000000000000000 (80-bit)
>
>  Round key 1: 0000000000000000
>  Round key 2: c000000000000000
>  Round key 3: 5000180000000001
>  Round key 4: 60000a0003000001
>  Round key 5: b0000c0001400062
>  Round key 6: 900016000180002a
>  Round key 7: 0001920002c00033
>  Round key 8: a000a0003240005b
>  Round key 9: d000d4001400064c
>  Round key 10: 30017a001a800284
>  Round key 11: e01926002f400355
>  Round key 12: f00a1c0324c005ed
>  Round key 13: 800d5e014380649e
>  Round key 14: 4017b001abc02876
>  Round key 15: 71926802f600357f
>  Round key 16: 10a1ce324d005ec7
>  Round key 17: 20d5e21439c649a8
>  Round key 18: c17b041abc428730
>  Round key 19: c926b82f60835781
>  Round key 20: 6a1cd924d705ec19
>  Round key 21: bd5e0d439b249aea
>  Round key 22: 07b077abc1a8736e
>  Round key 23: 426ba0f60ef5783e
>  Round key 24: 41cda84d741ec1d5
>  Round key 25: f5e0e839b509ae8f
>  Round key 26: 2b075ebc1d0736ad
>  Round key 27: 86ba2560ebd783ad
>  Round key 28: 8cdab0d744ac1d77
>  Round key 29: 1e0eb19b561ae89b
>  Round key 30: d075c3c1d6336acd
>  Round key 31: 8ba27a0eb8783ac9
>  Round key 32: 6dab31744f41d700
>  
>  Round Output 1: ffffffff00000000
>  Round Output 2: 80ff00ffff008000
>  Round Output 3: 4036c837b7c88c09
>  Round Output 4: 73c2cd26b6192359
>  Round Output 5: 41d7be58531e4446
>  Round Output 6: 182ef861ad62fd1c
>  Round Output 7: 0ea0a5b67effc5a4
>  Round Output 8: bba0b848a113e080
>  Round Output 9: fa943423a9142338
>  Round Output 10: 69f2e22d63684d54
>  Round Output 11: 548a4b63c330a59d
>  Round Output 12: d75f955fa228e4ca
>  Round Output 13: 44255864103841f9
>  Round Output 14: e2cc9004363f6c12
>  Round Output 15: c36682c5cd375421
>  Round Output 16: 597db55cc2a5d9b6
>  Round Output 17: e67ce40e71b8b713
>  Round Output 18: 751df6d6807b5b59
>  Round Output 19: b948414e23332c93
>  Round Output 20: 5b75890dcfb3d563
>  Round Output 21: 5679203168278f5a
>  Round Output 22: 17c377c413fa45a3
>  Round Output 23: 262a2de73b5f3ecd
>  Round Output 24: d3a053128b4d7bb3
>  Round Output 25: 7db29209c28a20fa
>  Round Output 26: 62050c9940f400b9
>  Round Output 27: 65d50da21fbcc09f
>  Round Output 28: 6a50663c540d862f
>  Round Output 29: c79b8ff00a48df35
>  Round Output 30: 4a38c5e00283fba1
>  Round Output 31: 38d2f04c34635345
>  
>  Ciphertext: 5579c1387b228445
> ```

Comment: Aren't those round keys of 80 bits?

Answer (score 2):

In the [original paper (pp. 16)](https://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2007/47270450/47270450.pdf) one can find the requested test-vectors.
The paper includes test vectors for all four cases you request (one or both of key and plaintext are $00...00$ or $FF...FF$).
The following table shows the test vectors:

```
Plaintext         | Key                    | Ciphertext
------------------|------------------------|-----------------
00000000 00000000 | 00000000 00000000 0000 | 5579C138 7B228445
00000000 00000000 | FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF | E72C46C0 F5945049
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF | 00000000 00000000 0000 | A112FFC7 2F68417B
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF | FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF | 3333DCD3 213210D2
```

Comment: While the phrasing in the question may be a bit ambiguous, the way I interpret it is that the OP would like some *other* test vectors than these "usual" ones, for further testing.

Answer (score 1):

| Plaintext | Key | Ciphertext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000 00000000 | 00000000 00000000 0000 | 5579C138 7B228445 |
| 00000000 00000000 | FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF | E72C46C0 F5945049 |
| FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF | 00000000 00000000 0000 | A112FFC7 2F68417B |
| FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF | FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF | 3333DCD3 213210D2 |

I was not able to get the round keys that are mentioned above. I got the below round keys and in the end, got the expected result.

For the first test case the round keys (PRESENT-80) are as follows:

```
Round Key 1:C0000000000000008000
Round Key 2:50001800000000010000
Round Key 3:60000A00030000018000
Round Key 4:B0000C00014000620000
Round Key 5:900016000180002A800C
Round Key 6:0001920002C000330005
Round Key 7:A000A0003240005B8006
Round Key 8:D000D4001400064C000B
Round Key 9:30017A001A80028480C9
Round Key 10:E01926002F4003550050
Round Key 11:F00A1C0324C005ED806A
Round Key 12:800D5E014380649E00BD
Round Key 13:4017B001ABC028768C93
Round Key 14:71926802F600357F050E
Round Key 15:10A1CE324D005EC786AF
Round Key 16:20D5E21439C649A80BD8
Round Key 17:C17B041ABC4287304935
Round Key 18:C926B82F6083578150E6
Round Key 19:6A1CD924D705EC19EAF0
Round Key 20:BD5E0D439B249AEABD83
Round Key 21:07B077ABC1A8736E135D
Round Key 22:426BA0F60EF5783E0E6D
Round Key 23:41CDA84D741EC1D52F07
Round Key 24:F5E0E839B509AE8FD83A
Round Key 25:2B075EBC1D0736ADB5D1
Round Key 26:86BA2560EBD783ADE6D5
Round Key 27:8CDAB0D744AC1D777075
Round Key 28:1E0EB19B561AE89B83AE
Round Key 29:D075C3C1D6336ACDDD13
Round Key 30:8BA27A0EB8783AC96D59
Round Key 31:6DAB31744F41D7008759

Output: 5579C1387B228445
```

Comment: Those do appear to be the same round keys but without the 0th round key which is direct use of the input key. I think that your implementations are in agreement.

Comment: Ya, my bad. Just noticed that they're all missing last 4 bytes of the key. Otherwise they're the same. Just pasted this for debugging purposes.