# Test vectors for Piccolo algorithm?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, test-vectors, lightweight

I'm looking for Test Vectors to test my implementation of PICCOLO. I would like to test a different input from the usual where the key and the plaintext are either 000..000 or FFF...FFF.

I wrote algorithm in C, like described one in paper http://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2011/69170343/69170343.pdf    but i did not get the same results like test results. I just want to compare my middle steps like in post  [Test vectors for PRESENT algorithm?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/test-vectors-for-present-algorithm)

Comment: What's wrong with adding instrumentation (a few printf) to that [reference code](https://github.com/Daeinar/piccolo) which results seem to match the paper that you use as reference?

Comment: Problem is final output, it is not equals with one in paper. I asked if someone has correct program so I can compare middle key results and other step?

Comment: My link is to a probably correct program.