# Where can I find test vectors for the PRESENT cipher with a 128-bit key?

Tags: block-cipher, test-vectors, present

Where can I find the test vectors for the PRESENT block cipher with a 128-bit key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test vectors for PRESENT algorithm?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/test-vectors-for-present-algorithm)

Comment: The possible duplicate does not appear to actually answer this question, despite the title making it look like it obviously should. None of the links on that page appear to supply test vectors for the 128-bit version of present.

Answer (score 1):

The test vectors for PRESENT cipher 128 bit key size are:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\def\tabentry#1 {{\scriptstyle\mathtt{#1 }}}
K & P & C  \\
\hline
\tabentry 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 & \tabentry 0x0000000000000000 & \tabentry 0x96db702a2e6900af \\
\tabentry 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff & \tabentry 0x0000000000000000 & \tabentry 0x13238c710272a5d8 \\
\tabentry 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 & \tabentry 0xffffffffffffffff & \tabentry0x3c6019e5e5edd563 \\
\tabentry0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff & \tabentry0xffffffffffffffff & \tabentry0x628d9fbd4218e5b4 \\
\end{array}
$$

The intermediate values of `0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` key schedule are:

\begin{align*}
\def\keysched#1:#2 {#1&:\mathtt{0x#2}}
\keysched 0:ffffffffffffffff \\
\keysched 1:22ffffffffffffff \\
\keysched 2:2dffffffffffffff \\
\keysched 3:148bffffffffffff \\
\keysched 4:19b7fffffffffffe \\
\keysched 5:74522ffffffffffe \\
\keysched 6:7966dffffffffffe \\
\keysched 7:47d148bffffffffe \\
\keysched 8:40e59b7ffffffffd \\
\keysched 9:871f4522fffffffd \\
\keysched 10:8003966dfffffffd \\
\keysched 11:f11c7d148bfffffd \\
\keysched 12:fa000e59b7fffffc \\
\keysched 13:e2c471f4522ffffc \\
\keysched 14:ede8003966dffffc \\
\keysched 15:328b11c7d148bffc \\
\keysched 16:3db7a000e59b7ffb \\
\keysched 17:d4ca2c471f4522fb \\
\keysched 18:d9f6de8003966dfb \\
\keysched 19:a25328b11c7d148f \\
\keysched 20:1d67db7a000e59b2 \\
\keysched 21:01894ca2c471f457 \\
\keysched 22:14759f6de8003963 \\
\keysched 23:a30625328b11c7d4 \\
\keysched 24:ec51d67db7a000e3 \\
\keysched 25:d68c1894ca2c4719 \\
\keysched 26:6bb14759f6de8005 \\
\keysched 27:fb5a30625328b11a \\
\keysched 28:00aec51d67db7a07 \\
\keysched 29:1bed68c1894ca2c3 \\
\keysched 30:a902bb14759f6def \\
\keysched 31:2c6fb5a30625328c \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for your timely respose